# How can I delete my google cloud platform billing account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing

I have created some billing accounts but I want to delete some as you can see in the picture, I want to delete `BillingAccount1` and `BillingAccount2` since Google told me that there are some issues in these accounts.

[image]

[In the documents](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account), I did find the delete button on the system.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account#delete_a_billing_account):

> Cloud Billing accounts cannot be deleted.

So, you can close the billing accounts, but those can not be deleted.

The best thing you can do is keep them closed and not use them.

I can see you still have a project linked to `BillingAccount2`, so you could move that project to a billing account that it's working. Other than that, not much you can do.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to remove the credit card which connected to your billing account, just go to: https://pay.google.com/gp/w/u/0/home/activity
and remove it from there.

Dunno why Google made it so inconvenient

Comment: After hours of searching, this is the only thing that worked, thank you!

Comment: They show all your subscriptions only in this page. I couldn't remove my card from cloud console even after closing my billing account because I was already subscribed to YouTube Premium which I hadn't realized until I came here. Don't know if they would have allowed me to remove it otherwise but anyway, GCP is a UX mess.

Comment: You can delete the card but the billing account still there in Cloud console, clearly not the answer the OP is looking for

Comment: Consider the amount of points this answer gained as oppose to the accepted answer, I will say that this answer is relevant even though it doesn't answer the original question. I guess most people worry about leaving their credit details more than having an empty billing account

Answer (score 0):

As google mention you cannot delete any of your account billing.

> After creation, Cloud Billing accounts cannot be canceled or deleted. Even if you close your Cloud Billing account, the Cloud Billing account information is retained for reporting and auditing purposes.
> [Source](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/close-or-reopen-billing-account)