# Problems with google cloud billing account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am facing issues with my Google Cloud Billing account . I got a mail that my billing account had been suspended as my card details could not be verified so I just closed that billing account and by mistake ended up creating another billing account . Again , the second account has also been suspended as my card details cannot be verified although , I have given all the details properly .
I do not have any payments to make for any services as I didn't use any but both my billing accounts are closed right now . So , will this cause any harm to my google account/gmail or is there any action that google takes for not being able to verify your card details . Also , is there any solution to delete both the billing accounts as they are just closed , I want to delete them permanently.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I delete my google cloud platform billing account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49109139/how-can-i-delete-my-google-cloud-platform-billing-account)

Comment: Yes , to some extent but is there any problem if the billing accounts are just suspended , that we don't use them at all.  Does Google inflict any action on my main Google account if I just keep my billing accounts closed for a long period of time,  given the fact that they are already suspended? . Also , I have no payments to make and moreover , I don't wish to use any of the services

Comment: Have you tried to contact [Google Cloud Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub)?

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza , yes but the only solution I am getting is to verify the card that I'm using for payment .

Comment: If you don't use any services you shouldn't worry about your Google account because with GCP you pay only for what you used.

Comment: Google offers the ability to prepay your account. Your question lacks details on why your credit card could not be verified, the country you are in, etc. This topic has been covered on Stack Overflow and on the Internet numerous times. https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manual-payment

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley , I reside in India and am using a debit card for the transaction

Comment: Google has details for users in India. https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/resolve-issues#resolve-india-autopay

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley for the help . I think I found out the reasons why the account might have been suspended . I have closed all my billing accounts and no projects are associated with any billing account , so , if my billing accounts remain suspended , would that cause a problem . I am no longer interested in using any of Google Cloud Platform services would surely not be using them in the future . So , since I have already my closed my billing accounts and I have no payments to make , will the suspension of my billing accounts due to problem in verification of the card cause any issues?

Comment: Delete your Payments Account, Billing Account and then terminate the project.